# ActiveRecord use SQL foreign_key with on_delete cycles

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord

I have

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one  :contact, :inverse_of => :organization, :foreign_key => 'organization_id'
  has_many :contacts, :inverse_of => :address_book, :foreign:key => 'address_book_id'
end
```

I would like to add a SQL constraint so when a company is deleted, both its contact and contacts are deleted.

I therefore add (since I am Rails > 4.2) to my migration:

```
def change
  add_foreign_key :contacts, :organizations, column: :organization_id, on_delete: :cascade
  add_foreign_key :contacts, :organizations, column: :address_book_id, on_delete: :cascade    
end
```

but this raises

```
TinyTds::Error: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'fk_rails_7e223a7fac' on table 'contacts' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.: ALTER TABLE [contacts] ADD CONSTRAINT [fk_rails_7e223a7fac]
```

(I use SQL Azure with TinyTds and ActiveRecord sql adaptor).

From what I understand, this occurs since if a same organization is referenced by a Contact on both :contact and :contacts, it will have multiple cascade paths. Now, how can I still have cascading with such a setup?

Comment: is `dependent: :destroy` not sufficient?

Comment: Nope :) https://robots.thoughtbot.com/referential-integrity-with-foreign-keys

Comment: @muichikne - there are a lot of discussions around this. Some people prefer having extra constraint in their database (which makes your life slightly harder from my experience as you cannot remove whatever you want from the database any more) and there are others (including me) preferring not to use methods like `delete_all` and use `destroy_all` instead.